# I want to remove OK button from the ant design time picker I tried too many times but it's not resolving please check and let me know

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

```
<TimePicker
    onChange={handlePickTimeChange}
    placeholder="Start Time"
    format="HH:mm"
    allowClear={true}
    showNow={false}
    showOK={false}
    disabledTime={disabledTime}
    style={{ textShadow: '0px 0px black' }}
/>
```

`showNow={false}` this is working in my code but `showOK={false}` not working,  I was written lot's of logic and trid many times but not happened anything.

I expect who can write correct code for me that will be work properly.

Comment: _"showNow={false} this is working in my code but showOK={false} not working"_ - the former is one of the defined properties, https://ant.design/components/time-picker#api - whereas the latter appears to be just something you made up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a direct prop called `showOK` to control the visibility of the OK button.

```
 <TimePicker
      onChange={handlePickTimeChange}
      placeholder="Start Time"
      format="HH:mm"
      allowClear={true}
      showNow={false}
      disabledTime={disabledTime}
      style={{ textShadow: '0px 0px black' }}
    />
```